# Will google index the correct URL for hashbang/escaped_fragment content

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, hashbang

I have recently read Google's [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling) as I was wondering how to correctly prepare my dynamic site, which uses hashbang navigation, for SEO.
I understand now that for  `mysite.com/#!/foobar` I should serve an equivalent html snapshot at `mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=foobar`.

I just want to know if google then correctly indexes my page as `http://example.com/#!/foobar`
or if it uses this `escaped_fragment` url? I'm assuming (but would like to be sure) it will correctly use my hashbang url for the search results but that the indexed content was taken from the `escaped_fragment` page.

Some confirmation would help me sleep better. thanks

Comment: I think that's more or less the purpose of it yes. Slightly off topic - I absolutely hate this design pattern, it's hugely irritating when browsing with no-script and I generally avoid sites that use it for that reason alone.

Comment: Agreed. Using this to load your page content is a [very bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: Thanks. What navigation techniques would you recommend for AJAX sites or other dynamic sites where states should be bookmarkable etc, in that case?

Comment: and just for interest's sake, why do you browse with no-script?

Comment: Fix url: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Answer (score 0):

By default, google will create escaped_fragment url  for your page. That could end up looking ugly.

You should redirect escaped_fragment url to a page page with a prettier url using 301

Say your server gets a URL request from googlebot/any hashbang compliant crawler such as "targetPage?_escaped_fragment_=command=play%26id=4ee7af"

You should have your targetPage  accepts  targetPage?_escaped_fragment_= .... and created a 301 redirect to  itself as "targetPage?command=play&id=4ee7af" ( or any other pretty url  as long as it is to the same page)

If you were using J2EE you could create a servlet filter to intercept and 301 redirect to cleaner url of the same page.